# Android Studio get step count at onResume

Tags: android-studio, android-sensors

I would like to get the step count at `onResume` and not at `onSensorChanged`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply receive the Steps count in the onSensorChanged and save them in a variable or in any shared storage (i.e. Shared Preferences). Later you can access the steps from the variable/shared storage where you saved them initially.

I don't know what you're trying to achieve but this is how you can get the steps count in the onResume. Steps will keep updating in the variable/shared storage on every onSensorChanged and when onResume is called, you can updated your UI (or whatever needs to be done with the steps count) with the updated steps count value.